# Guaranteed rollback in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transaction, rollback, truncate

I'm trying to create a job in SSIS to truncate a table, read from a data source and rewrite the table, so only 2 steps (1 Truncate and 2 Select + Insert). I need to guarantee a Truncate's Rollback in the event that the insert has errors.

I tried with the sequence container and the TransactionOption but SSIS doesn't want to cooperate.

PS I can't do too many operations because I have millions of records and I need rapid performance.

Answer (score 2):

By using Sequence Containers (Sequence, For Loop, ForEach Loop) in SSIS, you can make use of the property **TransactionOption**. This allows you to specify the transactional behaviour of the tasks in your package, and the package itself to rollback if any tasks fail.

If you stick your tasks in a Sequence Container and set `TransactionOption=Required`, and configure all Tasks within the Container to `TransactionOption=Supported`, they will all join the transaction started in the Sequence Container, and if any fail, the transaction will be rolled back even a truncate table sql command.
This is the way you would generally have to do it to get what you are looking for. I do not know why in your case the truncate rollback is not performed. You may want to run a test using the configuration below.

1. create a container
2. Set `TransactionOption=Required` for the container
3. place a sql task inside the container with the truncate table statement
4. set `TransactionOption=Supported` for the truncate sql task
5. add a sql task with select 1/0 (it will fail)
6. set `TransactionOption=Supported` for the truncate sql task

You need to have in place DTC, **distributed transactor coordinator**.

First verify if the Distribute Transaction Coordinato Service is
running on both source server and ssis server

1. Go to "Administrative Tools > Services"
2. Turn on the "Distribute Transaction Coordinator" Service if it is not running

If it is running, on the source database server

1. Go to "Administrative Tools > Component Services"
2. On the left navigation tree, go to "Component Services - Computers - My Computer" (you may need to double click and wait as some nodes
   need time to expand)
3. Right click on "My Computer", select "Properties"
4. Select "MSDTC" tab
5. Click "Security Configuration"
6. Make sure you check "Network DTC Access", "Allow Remote Client",
   "Allow Inbound/Outbound", "Enable TIP" (Some option may not be
   necessary, have a try to get your configuration)
7. The service will restart
8. you my need to rebbot your server if it still doesn't work

On the ssis running instance use the same above procedure to open the
"Security Configuration" setting, make sure you check "Network DTC
Access", "Allow Inbound/Outbound" option, restart service and computer
if necessary.

hoping to be useful :-)

Comment: i tryed yet but....
["Primary" Connection Manager] Error: The SSIS runtime was unable to insert the OLE DB connection into a distributed transaction with error 0x8004D024 "The operations manager has disabled its support for remote / network operations.".

Comment: Ok you need to do a distributed transaction. I add how to do it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The other approach beyond MBuschi's fine answer is to handle the transaction explicitly.

[image]

To make this work, you need to right click on the Connection Manager and change the default `RetainSameConnection` property from False to `True`.

With that change, there will be one connection held open for the duration of the package execution so optimize your operations.

The main sequence container opens the transaction literally `BEGIN TRAN;` and then truncate your table, load the data. If all goes to plan, the happy path fires and you issue `COMMIT`. If any of the tasks inside the Sequence Container fail, the Failure path fires and an explicit `ROLLBACK` is issued.